# В Google Chrome новая вкладка и результаты поиска превращаются в крякозябры

Tags: google-chrome

Вчера ни с того ни с сего Google Chrome стал вместо обычной новой вкладки и результатов поиска показывать это:
[image: Новая вкладка]
[image: Если что-то искать]
Такая же ситуация наблюдается в FireFox:
[image: В другом браузере]
Подскажите, что это может быть?

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/5Toplm6lXPQ

Comment: И другое по запросу "gws_rd=ssl"

Comment: @MikhailSibirev, у меня проблема не в этом, и не только в firefox

Comment: @MikhailSibirev, и это не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё стало работать как надо, когда зашёл на google.com.ua и вернулся назад на google.ru. Странно, но проблема пропала.

Answer (score 1):

1. полностью удаляем Kaspersky Internet Security
2. качаем Утилиту удаления продуктов Лаборатории Касперского (kavremover) - https://support.kaspersky.ru/1464#block1
3. запускаем эту утилиту и чистим хвосты, если они остались.

После этого можно поставить KIS новой версии, если он прям так нужен.

Comment: Обоснуйте. Я вот не увидел связи между вопросом и Kaspersky Internet Security.

Comment: Kaspersky уже довольно давно является причиной различных проблем с Chrome. То сертификаты и https, то кривой рендеринг. На официальных форумах Google этот совет помог пользователям.

Comment: Тогда добавьте эту информацию на вопрос, желательно со ссылкой на форумы